# Programmatically downloading email body from gmail url

Tags: perl, gmail

I want to extract the body of an email from a gmail url: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/FMfBlahwDrHlsBlahlzHWzQXHFKhjpTp1`

I am using the Perl module: [`Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail) which gets me sequential access to the email inboxes and their imap ids. It also has a search method for searching emails. It also provides imap thread ids of each email.

But I haven't found an easy way to link the thread's URL in the browser to a particular imap email id so I can extract the body.

Comment: It should be possible using the `UID SEARCH X-GM-MSGID` command, see [this link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions) for more information. I am not sure if `Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail` supports it though

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like this Perl module might do the trick: https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, though it's a bit convoluted:

1. Navigate to the gmail message thread of interest in your browser
2. Run the following JS in the developer console (or better, programmatically with Applescript, if using Safari, or some other browser automation program like WWW::Mechanize::Chrome) to get the "legacy" thread id:

`document.querySelector('[data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id')`

3. Once you get the thread id, you then need to convert it to a decimal number. In Perl:

`my $dec_num = sprintf("%d", hex($thread_id));`

4. Now that you have obtained the thread id, you can use the Perl `Mail::IMAPClient` cpan module to obtain the messages in the thread by searching on the thread id:

```
use Mail::IMAPClient;
my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
  Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
  User     => 'me',
  Password => 'blah',
  Ssl      => 1,
  Uid      => 1,
);

my $folders = $imap->select('INBOX');

my $msgs = $imap->search("X-GM-THRID", $decimal_thread_id);
foreach my $msg (@$msgs) { 
  my $msg_st = $imap->message_string($msg);
  # slice and dice messages with modules listed below
}
```

Now you can use cpan modules like `Email::MIME` and `Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper` and `Email::MIME::Encodings` to parse the emails in `$msgs` and decode them as necessary.